# Are the statusQueryGetUri and terminatePostUri endpoints of Durable Azure Functions intended to be used directly?

Tags: azure, azure-durable-functions

I'm learning Azure Durable Functions (ADF). I want to use this service to create an API that can be used to trigger long running jobs.

When you have an ADF that you trigger, it not only starts the task, but also returns a list of endpoints that can be used to manage the task. These endpoint include URLS named `statusQueryGetUri` and `terminatePostUri`.

I'm wondering what is the recommended practice for this. Should these endpoints be presented directly to the target audience of the API, so they can query the status or terminate the tasks via these Azure-created URLs?

Or are these endpoints supposed to be used internally? And should I write custom target audience facing endpoints, such as `/getJobStatus/2` or `/terminateJob/2` that internally call the URLs in `statusQueryGetUri` or `terminatePostUri`